# Automating Authentication Programmatically

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication

First of all, the screen below is the popup window when i requested an asp web page. When i am authenticated, it responses an xml data.

1.What is the type of this authentication method. How is it managed?
2.How can i bypass programmatically(using C sharp) this login screen by supplying necessary credentials.

[login screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r4qQi.png)

Answer (score 1):

thanks, you helped very much. i solved it. just the code like below is enough.

```
    string url = "www.testweb.com";
    WebRequest myReq = WebRequest.Create(url);
    myReq.Timeout = 1000000000;
    string username = "Administrator";
    string password = "123456";
    myReq.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(username, password);
    WebResponse wr = myReq.GetResponse();
    Stream receiveStream = wr.GetResponseStream();
    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(receiveStream, Encoding.UTF8);
    string content = reader.ReadToEnd();
```